# Redmine: Some way to place a ticket on "Hold" aka Closed Temporarily?

Tags: project-management, redmine

In Redmine, is there a way to "temporarily close" a ticket so that it doesn't show up in most reports, but then have it re-open after awhile?

We have a status called "On Hold" which means it's still a valid issue, but we have no immediate plans to address it. It would be great if an "On Hold" issue could be closed for a specified period of time, say from 2-8 weeks.

I've made a feature request on the Redmine site, but I'm posting here because I'm interested in finding out if there's a way to do this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way (using a standard install, anyway) to make those issues appear `Closed` without actually enabling the `Issue Closed` flag for that status, but a nice way to get them out of the way when viewing issue lists is to create a Custom Query from a search that excludes the ones you don't want, and then make that query public.

For example, I have a public custom query called "Not paused or complete" that excludes issues with a status of `On Hold, Resolved, Closed, Declined`. Any user can then apply this filter when viewing the issue list for a project, and it will show only active issues. Unfortunately, this won't affect reports such as roadmap reports - the issues will be shown the same as all other `Open` issues in these areas.

Comment: Precisely what we ended up doing, thank you Simon. I think the On Hold feature would be a great addition for Redmine someday, so much so that I'd add it myself -- if I cared enough to learn Ruby. ;)